# Auto Mapper is NULL after set up

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I'm trying to get [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) working in our application. We're using version 6.0.2. I've followed a plethora of examples and here's what I've got so far:

**ViewModels\AutoMapperProfileConfiguration.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using Models;
using ViewModels;

namespace App
{
    public class AutoMapperProfileConfiguration : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfileConfiguration()
        {
            CreateMap<Models.Source, ViewModels.Destination>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private MapperConfiguration _mapperConfiguration { get; set; }
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        _mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfileConfiguration());
        });

        ...
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => _mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());

        ...
    }
}
```

**Controllers\BaseController.cs**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public BaseController(..., IMapper mapper)
    {
        ...

        _mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

**Controllers\HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

    public HomeController(..., IMapper mapper ) :
    base(..., mapper )
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Action()
    {
        Model.Source x = ...;

        ViewModel.Destination y = _mapper.Map<ViewModel.Destination>(x);

        return View(y);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it seems that `CreateMapper` is not working properly. Here's what I get in the list of services after `services.AddSingleton`:

[image: services]

And whenever the **BaseController** is used, here's what `mapper` looks like:

[image]

And here's what happens when it gets to the **HomeController**:

[image]

And this error occurs when it tries to map the source to the destination:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What is causing this? Is it related to my set up? My assumption is that it all stems from the `services` having what looks like a NULL instance for the mapper. But I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Try just `services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(_mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());`

Comment: The difference here is that you could be implicitly capturing the `_mapperConfiguration` closure. So by using a factory you could be defering the call to `CreateMapper` until the instance has been destroyed... possibly - however, with the way I describe, you're actually giving over an instance of the mapper at the time you create it (with all the configuration etc..)

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you trying to inject IMapper interface into services ? Why dont to go with a simplier way like calling static methods `Mapper.Map<ViewModel.Destination>(x)`

Comment: So I was still having trouble even with all these suggestions. I went and debugged it some more (separated my code out in to separate lines), and found out that the exception (`System.NullReferenceException`) was actually coming from the `list` I was trying to add the object too; the `list` was never initialized! Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Since AutoMapperProfileConfiguration inherits Profile, all you need is to use ***[AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)*** middle-ware.

You could install it via this NuGet -
[AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/)

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      ...
      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddAutoMapper();
   }
}
```

*Note: Remove automapper related code inside your Startup.cs. You don't need any of those.*

Answer (score 1):

Let `AutoMapper` singletons do the work.

```
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfileConfiguration>();
        });
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddSingleton(s => Mapper.Instance);
   }
```

Then the injected `IMapper` should contain the profiles.